# Pandas groupby and apply - getting a new DataFrame over the groupby variable

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use `pandas.DataFrame.groupby['x']` in order to make calculation on the grouped `df`, by `x`.

Problem arise when `'x'` repeats more then once. apply function will do the calculations as many times as `'x'` repeats, though I only need the 'aggregated' values (It's not really an *aggregation* but more like - *processing*).

Here's a toy example:

```
def simulate_complicated_func(df):
    # This function simulates complicate calculations
    returned_col_names = ['calc1', 'calc2', 'calc3']

    df['calc1'] = ''.join(df['var1'])
    df['calc2'] = df['var2'].mean()
    df['calc3'] = ''.join(df['var1']) + str(df['var2'].max())

    return df[['id'] + returned_col_names]

df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['id1', 'id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id3', 'id3'],
                   'var1':['abc', 'cba', 'abc', 'cba', 'abc', 'cba'],
                   'var2':[9, 4, 7, 4, 1, 3]})

print(df)

    id var1  var2
0  id1  abc     9
1  id1  cba     4
2  id2  abc     7
3  id3  cba     4
4  id3  abc     1
5  id3  cba     3

res_df = df.groupby(['id']).apply(simulate_complicated_func).drop_duplicates()
print(res_df)

    id      calc1     calc2       calc3
0  id1     abccba  6.500000     abccba9
2  id2        abc  7.000000        abc7
3  id3  cbaabccba  2.666667  cbaabccba4
```

The output is exactly what I want, but it's not efficient. Is there a better way doing it using pandas?

### Edit: Optimize how?

If we'll add a `print` statement to `simulate_complicated_func()`

```
def simulate_complicated_func(df):
    # This function simulates complicate calculations
    print("function called")
    # ...
```

We can see that the code will print it 6 times:

```
function called
function called
function called
function called
function called
function called
```

In reality, we only need to access this function 3 times (the number of groups created by groupby).

Comment: What is size of real data? And what is number of groups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea is return `Series` from custom function, so `drop_duplicates` is not necessary:

```
def simulate_complicated_func(df):
    # This function simulates complicate calculations
    returned_col_names = ['calc1', 'calc2', 'calc3']

    a = ''.join(df['var1'])
    b = df['var2'].mean()
    c = ''.join(df['var1']) + str(df['var2'].max())

    return pd.Series([a,b,c], index=returned_col_names)

res_df = df.groupby(['id']).apply(simulate_complicated_func).reset_index()
print(res_df)
    id      calc1     calc2       calc3
0  id1     abccba  6.500000     abccba9
1  id2        abc  7.000000        abc7
2  id3  cbaabccba  2.666667  cbaabccba4
```

Another idea is use [`DataFrameGroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) but it is possible only for processing all columns with aggregated functions like `join` and `mean`. Function `agg` working with each column separately, so `cal3` is not possible easy/effective way count - is necessary again custom function and last join output together:

```
def simulate_complicated_func(df):
    # This function simulates complicate calculations
    returned_col_names = ['calc3']
    c = ''.join(df['var1']) + str(df['var2'].max())
    return pd.Series([c], index=returned_col_names)

d = {'var1': ''.join, 'var2':'mean'}
cols = {'var1':'calc1','var2':'calc2'}
g = df.groupby(['id'])

df1 = g.agg(d).rename(columns=cols)
print (df1)
         calc1     calc2
id                      
id1     abccba  6.500000
id2        abc  7.000000
id3  cbaabccba  2.666667

df2 = df.groupby(['id']).apply(simulate_complicated_func)
print(df2)
          calc3
id             
id1     abccba9
id2        abc7
id3  cbaabccba4

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).reset_index()
print (df)
    id      calc1     calc2       calc3
0  id1     abccba  6.500000     abccba9
1  id2        abc  7.000000        abc7
2  id3  cbaabccba  2.666667  cbaabccba4
```

Comment: Thanks jezrael!, but that's just a toy example. In reality the function is much more complicated and aggregation in-built functions don't work. Is there no way in Pandas to groupby 'id', do a calculation 1 time on the grouped by object and return the result, per 'id' ?

Comment: @EranMoshe - Do you think my first solution?

Comment: It's more Pythonic, but still calling the function all the time (6 in the example) instead of 3 (because only 3 unique 'id')

Comment: @EranMoshe - Why do you think `6` times ? How do you test it? In my opinion it call `4` times - 3 + 1 because [warning](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#flexible-apply) - 1. apply is call 2 times.

Comment: I've added a print function there to see how many times it has been called

Comment: Try `df2 = df.groupby(['id']).apply(lambda x: print (x))`

Comment: Hold it! Testing your Series solution, it does seem to work better! Gimme a few minutes please.